# Как получить доступ к настройкам объекта?

Tags: c#, unity3d

У меня есть 2 объекта. При входе в триггер один из них(до этого невидимый(сделано через mask Interaction, выставил VisibleInsideMask)) должен появиться. После регистрации нажатия(в методе Update), оба объекта должны исчезнуть и переменная в контроллере анимаций должна поменяться. Как поменять mask Interaction? Или есть какой - то более рациональный способ?

Вот код который я использую:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class Interact : MonoBehaviour
{
    Rigidbody2D rb;
    Animator anim;
    public GameObject backpack;
    public GameObject button;
    public bool button_flag = false;
    public bool backpack_flag = false;
    publicc bool onTrig = false;
    void Awake()
    {
        rb = GetComponent <Rigidbody2D> ();
        anim = GetComponent <Animator> ();
        backpack = GameObject.FindGameObjectWithTag("Backpack");
        button = GameObject.FindGameObjectWithTag("Button");
    }

    private void OnTriggerStay2D(Collider2D col){
        if (backpack_flag == false && button_flag == false){
           // button.maskInteraction = SpriteMaskInteraction.VisibleOutsideMask;
           onTrig = True;
           backpack_flag = true;
           button_flag = true; // чтобы при повторном входе в триггер объекты не появились повторно.
        }
    }
    private void OnTriggerExit2D(Collider2D col){
        onTrig = false;
    }
    void Update()
    {
        if (onTrig && Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.E)){
            anim.isBag = true;
        }
    }
}
```